# Matlab data auto import and arrange program

Tags: excel, matlab, import-from-excel, bigdata

I have a large data set of smart meter which has more than a million rows. Data looks like this

```
customer number     time         load
1000                19501        1.5
....                 .....       ...
1000                 19548        1.5
1000                 19600        1.5
1000                   ...        ..  
1000                 19648         1.5
.                      .           .
1001                 19501        1.5
.                    .              .
```

Where first column is customer number, second column shows datand time and third column shows load. The date time starts from 19501, goes upto 48 and then it moves to 19600 and similarly for 7 days. Now i want to analsye this data in matlab using clustering. Firstly the data is in .txt format and due to its large number of rows, it does not open in matlab.

I opened it in excel (although it does not read it fully but still a million row data is good enough for me). I have reduced the number of rows so that they are readable to matlab and arranged the data using filters to have data arranged for individual customer from time 19501 till last reading for this customer and then second customer and so on.For my matlab clustering, I need the data from 19501-19548 hrs in 1 row, then next 48 readings for same customer in next row and so on till last customer.

Is it possible to have a matlab code which can do it automatically or shall I look for something in excel?

Comment: That is not a big data set. For 1 million rows that is less than 30MB once the data is parsed. Try `dlmread` it definitely can handle it!

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is i don't know how to open these files in matlab. I have 6 files, each is more than 400 mb but excel cannot read more than a million and something lines. i have tried dlmread but it does not appear to be doing anything. Anyother recommendation? I was looking at MapReduce, do you think that will help?

Comment: MapReduce is for Big data (data which does not fit your working memory), just get `dlmread` running. Please describe your issues using `dlmread`.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. dlmread was successful in handling it. I was making a mistake earlier which was problem. But although it was reading the data but still it did not serve the purpose as it read data with each delimiter in a new row and I needed data in a specific order.
Finally i used excel with recording a macro to setup the data in a specific order.